unable to upgrade package boot-repair on 22.04 jammy. boot-repair_4ppa2079_all.deb 404 Not found
I was trying to sudo apt-get upgrade
the sub-step of upgrading boot-repair is breaking my process.
I focused on upgrading boot-repair only. here is my attempt:
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS \n \l

root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-jammy.list 
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ jammy main
# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ jammy main
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# 
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# 
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                        
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease         
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install -y boot-repair 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  boot-sav
Suggested packages:
  boot-info dmraid lvm2 mdadm os-uninstaller zfsutils-linux
The following packages will be upgraded:
  boot-repair boot-sav
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 538 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 boot-sav all 4ppa2079
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 boot-repair all 4ppa2079
Err:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 boot-sav all 4ppa2079
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 boot-repair all 4ppa2079
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boot-repair/boot-sav_4ppa2079_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boot-repair/boot-repair_4ppa2079_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ping ppa.launchpadcontent.net
PING ppa.launchpadcontent.net (185.125.190.80) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ppa.launchpadcontent.net (185.125.190.80): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=136 ms
64 bytes from ppa.launchpadcontent.net (185.125.190.80): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=137 ms
^C
--- ppa.launchpadcontent.net ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 136.401/136.482/136.563/0.081 ms
root@poppy:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# 


Your machine's package sources appear to be out of date so update them, ie. https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair shows the package you're after no longer exists, as your system ran sudo apt update so long ago (you're looking for 2079 but that PPA is providing 2081 now)

This is another reason the package updtes should be applied in a reasonable matter of time.  Not updating at least every 3 to 6 months causes issues like this.

well, call me befuddled.
You can see in my original post, I had done an apt update (or at least an apt-get update). And that had not helped.
Today, I

moved all my /etc/apt/sources-list.d/*list flies somewhere else
apt update
move the sources-list.d/*list files back into their right place
apt update

Now, an apt upgrade worked without any problem.
It does not really make sense to me. Just something I read on some other post. I don't trust it as a recommended solution or even understand it. But, it did work for me.
